# Force reference to be on last page in latex

Tags: latex, biblatex

I'm writing an article for AAAI 2020 which has its own restriction- reference should be last and without figures after it. In addition, using \newpage or \pagebreak is not allowed at all.

Articles finished this way in.tex:

```
\section{ Acknowledgments}
 text text ...

\bibliography{gan.bib}
\end{document}
```

However, I got images after references.

[image]

Images and tables added this way:

```
\begin{table}[**!htbp**]
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l}
.....
\end{tabular}

\caption{aaaa}
\label{tbsamplers}
\end{table}
```

Any suggestion on how to fix my problem?

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre]

Comment: Is `\clearpage` allowed?